# scipy.optimize.least_squares return of only the solution

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to solve a set of linear equations using the [Lest Square Optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy-optimize-least-squares) function. As I have to use the solution vector x for further calculations, I want to return just x and not the rest.
I' just started using Python so I have no idea, How can I have to type the code, that **I get only x and not the whole return**.

I already tried codes like:

```
y= spo.least_squares(test_function, x0) [0]
```

but this nothing worked for me.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `scipy.optimize.least_squares` states:

> Returns:   `OptimizeResult` with the following fields defined:
>
> **x** : ndarray, shape (n,)
>
> Solution found.
>
> ...

This implies that you need to access result fields by name. To get only `x`, this should work:

```
y = spo.least_squares(test_function, x0).x
```

However, I don't want to encourage this usage. If the optimization fails for some reason you will never know. So unless you are absolutely sure it cannot fail, or you do not care if it fails don't use this pattern.

Better write a wrapper that deals with error handling and forwards `x` on success:

```
def my_lsq(*args, **kwargs):
    result = spo.least_squares(*args, **kwargs)

    if result.success:
        return result.x
    else:
        print(result)
        raise RuntimeError(result.message)
```

which can be used simply like `y = my_lsq(test_function, x0)`.